# Cant get java tests to click on different divs.Browser gets confused. Used Selenium IDE to export Java/Junit4/Web Driver

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, drupal, junit4

ANSWER IN OWN QUESTIONS COMMENTS

I am, on a scale of 1 to 10, a 3-4 in proficiency with java. My issues may be simply not knowing how the java logic works and because of it, may be the cause of my issue. I will try to explain as best I can.

**Background**
This past year I was charged with building tests for my companies site. We release site versions every week or two. Up until now, we had been using selenium IDE to run all our functional tests. Testing that content appears as it is expected and that new content can be created with our Drupal based site. Since taking over for the previous QA point person, I have come to see how it can be so limiting. Bring this to the attention of my boss, we opened an account with Browserstack Automate and have been exporting tests from selenium to Junit 4 (Webdriver) using Eclipse IDE. There are issues with the scripts that Selenium exports so I have been going through and correcting the errors as I see them appear. For the last 7 work days I have be stuck on the same issue however and have not found a proper fix that will continue to work always every time the script is run.

**Script Structure**
My scripts has included in it the following steps.

Variables:

```
// Node Input values
String nodeTitle1 = "QA Session Standard Test Page V1";
String nodeType = "articles";
String nodeSiteArea = "articles";
String nodeBodyText = "<p>This is a test page.</p>";

//Vertical Tabs and Section focus
By contentPage = By.cssSelector("#page #columns #page-node-form");
By contentMain = By.cssSelector("#page #columns #page-node-form .vertical-tabs .vertical-tabs-panes");
By contentTabs = By.cssSelector("#page #columns #page-node-form .vertical-tabs .vertical-tabs-list");
builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(contentTabs)).perform();
By tab1 = By.cssSelector("#page #columns #page-node-form .vertical-tabs .vertical-tabs-list .vertical-tab-button:nth-child(1)");
By tab2 = By.cssSelector("#page #columns #page-node-form .vertical-tabs .vertical-tabs-list .vertical-tab-button:nth-child(2)");
By tab3 = By.cssSelector("#page #columns #page-node-form .vertical-tabs .vertical-tabs-list .vertical-tab-button:nth-child(5)");
By tab4 = By.cssSelector("#page #columns #page-node-form .vertical-tabs .vertical-tabs-list .vertical-tab-button:nth-child(6)");
By tab6 = By.cssSelector("#page #columns #page-node-form .vertical-tabs .vertical-tabs-list .vertical-tab-button:nth-child(19)");
builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(contentMain)).perform();
checkPageIsReady();
```

1.Log in using the credentials provided. (The drupal admin bar appears.)
No Problems here

2.Create content, a standard page.
This works however in doing so, the attention (for lack of better word) of the browser is drown to the admin menu which leads to the next and main issue.

```
// Adding Content
WebElement content = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='admin-menu-menu']/li[2]/a"));
WebElement addContent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='admin-menu-menu']/li[2]/ul/li[2]/a"));
WebElement contentStandard = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='admin-menu-menu']/li[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[9]/a"));
builder.moveToElement(content).moveToElement(addContent).moveToElement(contentStandard).click().build().perform();
checkPageIsReady();
```

3.Add content information. (Title, Type, Body Text, ext..)
Most times there is not an issue here. Sometimes however, the script will error out because it says that it can not find the element. At the end of this section of code, instead of clicking the link again, it instead uses the admin menu and clicks to create a new standard page. The issue doesnt stop there.

```
// Editing Main Header Fields
By nodeTitleField = By.cssSelector("#page #columns #page-node-form .vertical-tabs .vertical-tabs-panes #edit-group_main .form-item-title #edit-title");
driver.findElement(nodeTitleField).sendKeys(nodeTitle1);
By nodeTypeField = By.cssSelector("#page #columns #page-node-form .vertical-tabs .vertical-tabs-panes #edit-group_main .field-name-field-type-form #edit-field-type-und");
driver.findElement(nodeTypeField).sendKeys(nodeType);

// Editing The Body Field
builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(contentMain)).perform();
By bodyPlainTextLink = By.cssSelector("#page #columns #page-node-form .vertical-tabs .vertical-tabs-panes #edit-group_main #edit-body #switch_edit-body-und-0-value");
driver.findElement(bodyPlainTextLink).click();
By bodyPlainTextArea = By.cssSelector("#page #columns #page-node-form .vertical-tabs .vertical-tabs-panes #edit-group_main #edit-body #edit-body-und-0-value");
driver.findElement(bodyPlainTextArea).sendKeys(nodeBodyText);
driver.findElement(bodyPlainTextLink).click();
```

4. Add more content information. There is more information that we must add to the page before it is ready to post. In order to reach the other fields to input more content, we must click a tab on the current content page that gives us options to add more info. I have the tabs selector set, however once again, the browser/scripts think I meant something in the admin bar, which is not where the tab is at all. It over looks the tab and creates instead another page. (As it did above.)

   // Editing Department Section

   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#page #columns #page-node-form .vertical-tabs .vertical-tabs-list .vertical-tab-button:nth-child(2)")).click();

**Conclusion and Thoughts**
My suspicion is the the browser, depending on where the mouse clicks happen last, the attention of the browser is on that div (aka the admin menu). But once the page loads, I need the test to find elements in the page content area. It is able to do that for the first few input fields, but after that, when I need it to click the Department tab, it gets hung up on the admin menu. Which makes no sense since right before that it was input information the the content page creation section.

PLEASE HELP! I might seriously loss all my hair for the stress of getting this done. I have explained to my boss that it is proving difficult but I cant use the same excuse (despite it being true) over and over again. StockOverflowes please help!

Comment: After many days, I have finally figured it out. By chance that is. Whenever I would builder.moveToElement that was an Input field, I would click on the element. This would for some reason mess with the the Webdriver finding the next element and instead picked a different element than the intended element.

Comment: Once I removed them and instead just driver.findElement.sendkeys to the element without mousing to it, it did the trick. Thank you to Jason and Manu for at least attempting to help. This issues has seriously made me loss faith in Stackoverflow. I would imagine that many others could have tried to help with such a basic question. When I better phrased my question, I was told by a Advanced user that my question was a repeat. No help, no suggestions, just a simple bull shit statement. The world is so self centered, its pretty sad.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the issue in *Point 3*, you should use the functionality of [implicit waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) (and/or [explicit waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)). As given in the documentation:

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

This will help stop the errors which you get which says that it can't find the element. If you still get the same error then maybe you should increase the wait time or using explicit wait for the element which throws an exception.

For implicit wait, after you initialize the webdriver, set the wait timeout period.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

For the issue in *Point 4*, I see that you are selecting the element by using a CSS Selector. I would suggest to either go for XPath (like you did in the example given in Point 2) instead or by selecting the Class name or Id. There must be another element in the same page (probably above the element you want to select) which has the same CSS Selectors (since it requires the same styling properties). Hence, the webdriver must be selecting that other element.

No matter which selectors you use, make sure that it is uniquely able to identify the element you want.

Comment: Thank you Jason for your reply. I have firepath on my browser, and whenever I checked if the ID or xpath were unique, its telling me they were. I have tried xpath and id as the selector, but the outcome is still the same. Interesting enough the CSS Selectors provides me with the most often working (fails firther down the test). I have tried both waits, and they dont seem to do the trick. Any further thoughts? Is there any way of telling the broswer to focus on a section of the page to look for its ids and classes? The admin menu is first div on the page, followed by the content page section.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Selenium Web Driver, your problem may cause one of following reasons.

1. Web driver tries to find the particular element before the page is fully loading.

for this I thiink it is better to use `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` at the begining of your method.

2. You may not  recognize the exact xpath/css selector (or what ever you are using to identify alements)

Are you using firebug to recognize elements? It is sometimes very difficult to find the exact XPath to identify elements. So, I recommend you to use Selenium IDE only to find the exact xpath (Just start record and click on the button you need. and then check the Selenium IDE. The xpath of the clicked area will be display. This is a very easy way to a beginer even if this is not formal)

This might help you. :)

Comment: Your suggestion in part 1 is much appreciated. However, part 2 I have done when I first built the test. The problem here is that in drupal, I am instructing the test to click on a menu option in the admin menu called "Add Content". The test proceeds to add the information in designated field. However, when we need tochanges tabs (for example the Publish tab) to tell the page to save, the element that it clicks (even though the xpath was unique to the tab(Publish)), it goes back to the admin menu and clicks the "add Content" button again.

Comment: Did you try with the link test 'Publish' instead of xpath or cssSelector ?

Comment: I have. No luck. I have been trying to fix this issue for 2 weeks now. I have scoured stackoverflow and its members many responses to similar issues.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.linkText("Publish")).click(); Just try this and tell me. Do not loose youeself. Every question have an answer :)